# Simple animation completely distorted on fbx export (2.8)

Tags: animation, .fbx

I have a simple door opening animation using a few rotations and translations, which in Blender looks like this, which is as it should (not withstanding gif quality):

[image: Correct animation]

However, after exporting to FBX, it is seriously deformed, and turns into this in other programs (unity, model viewer):

[image: Warped animation]

Whilst comical, I have no idea what's going wrong to cause this difference.  I've included my export settings and the appearance of the animation in the action editor below:

[image: FBX Export settings]
[image: Animation actions]
[[image: Object tree5]]

A lot of what I've read seems to indicating the use of armatures but surely that's not necessary for such a simple set of animations?  I assume what I'm doing is possible and I'm just missing some obvious settings.

Thanks in advance...